# sending data in push notification in android from php

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

I'm trying to develop a notification server which will notify user if certain event occurs on certain data. 
I want to pass those data along with notification so that i use that data to populate corresponding screen. So far i am able to just send notifications. I'm following below code for sending notification from my php side
Note: I am using Firebase.

https://github.com/adhishlal/Firebase-PHP/blob/master/sendnotification.php

Let me know if you need any detail

More Detail:

Just like facebook sends notification whenever one of our post gets a comment or like and on tapping over the notification the post opens. I want to implement the same. I want to send notification whenever user's post receives comment or like and on tapping over the notification I open that particular post. But for opening that post i need productId. As of now i'm able to send notification like "Some one has commented on your post". But when user tap over notification and i open my app then i don't know which post.
Below is the code on how i am handling notification

**MassagingService**

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static int id=0;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = null;
        Log.v(Constant.TAG,"Notification received");
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.v(Constant.TAG,"Notification Data:"+remoteMessage.getData());
            data = remoteMessage.getData(); //Want to receive this data
        }
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.v(Constant.TAG,"Notification:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            populateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), data);
        }
    }

    private void populateNotification(String body, Map<String, String> data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = null;

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).
                setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                setContentTitle("Pixyfi").
                setContentText(body).setSound(sound).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(id++, notification.build());
    }
}
```

**InstanceIdService**

```
public class PixyInstanceIdServce extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       /* UserService userService = ServiceFactory.getUserService();
        userService.registerToken(token);*/
        Log.v(Constant.TAG,"Token in Service:"+token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem in the question itself. A link to a repo is not enough. I'm also not really sure what the problem is. If the code doesn't self-explain that, it would help if you mention the problem explicitly or ask a single, concrete question about it.

Comment: Please see the updated post